# Скорректировать запрос sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть цикл foreach для двух айдишек. Внутри него есть обращение к БД по след. запросу:

```sql
SELECT to_char(pay.date_pay::abstime::timestamp, 'mm-yyyy') as date, 
       sum(pay.summ) as summ 
FROM payment as pay, 
     orders as ord 
WHERE pay.date_pay>=".$from_date." 
  AND pay.date_pay<=".$to_date." 
  AND pay.dropped=0 
  AND pay.plan_pay=0 
  AND pay.order_id=ord.order_id 
  AND ord.dogovor_town_id=".$v." 
  AND ord.is_test_object=0 
  AND ord.type=1 
  AND ord.dropped=0 
  AND ord.org_id=".$_SESSION['cl_org']." 
GROUP BY to_char(pay.date_pay::abstime::timestamp, 'mm-yyyy')
```

В первом обращении выводит следующее:

```
date    summ
01-2017 316701.39
02-2017 90481.2
03-2017 615416.87
04-2017 128000
05-2017 199520.16
06-2017 136000
07-2017 155460.96
08-2017 210719.03
09-2017 140837.33
10-2017 29611.93
11-2017 133548.37
12-2017 196811.27
```

При втором обращении:

```
date    summ
08-2017 28900
```

Хочу добиться такого:

```
date    summ
null    null
null    null
null    null
null    null
null    null
null    null
null    null
08-2017 28900
null    null
null    null
null    null
null    null
```

Т.е. чтобы даты и значения, которых нет, заменялись на null.

PostgreSQL 10.12, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit

Comment: *В первом обращении выводит следующее: ... При втором обращении:* Или изменяются параметры либо данные, или этого не может быть. Запрос - детерминированный.

Comment: "такой" вывод достигается с помощью LEFT JOIN

Comment: @Ипатьев Не подскажите как его применить в данном случае ? Не очень хорошо в sql. Буду очень признателен